# Non-abelian group of order 165 containing $\mathbb{Z}_{55}$.

Tags: group-theory

There is an example in this note http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/MATH370.2013/MATH370.notes.pdf (example 27.1.3 p. 56) that I cannot understand.
I attach the example.

**Example 27.1.3** Is there a non-abelian group of order $165$ containing $\mathbb{Z}_{55}$?

In such a group $G$, the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ must be normal (its index is the minimal one dividing
the order of $G$). Since there is always a 3-Sylow, we conclude that $G$ is a semi-direct product
$\mathbb{Z}_{55}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. This is determined by a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{3}\to Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{55}) \simeq(\mathbb{Z}_{55})^{\times}$ The
right hand side has order $\varphi(55) = 4\cdot 10$. Thus, the homomorphism is trivial and $G$ is a direct
product. It follows that $G$ must be commutative.

Question. Why the homomorphism is trivial? I can't see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homomorphism is trivial because the target group does not have subgroups of order 3 by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: By trivial, it means that $\phi (x) =1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ with $1\in (\mathbb{Z}_{55})^{\times}$?

Comment: Yes. it means the image of every element is 1.